# HTML div with padding

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I apologies in advance because I'm sure this is pretty straightforward but frontend isn't my field!
I have an html document I'm having issues with. The general structure is as follows:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 1cm;">
   <h4>Digital</h4>
   <h5 style="text-align: left;">Data Table:</h5>
   <table>
      <!-- the rest of the table here -->
   </table>
</div>
```

I have several of these div elements being generated by Jinja (python). My intention of the padding is to add space between the div elements in the page. This works as I'd expect if the  is empty (or very few rows) but as soon as the table grows the padding no longer works as I'd expect.

The HTML above gives me an output like the one below: (note how the empty space between 'Second table' and 'Third table' is smaller than between the space between 'First table' and 'second table'

[image]

Comment: if its jinja2 problem we cant help you without python code and template used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use margin-bottom instead and allow overflow on your parent element.

**for better result style the parent element that holds them**
use `flexbox`  or `grid`

Comment: Thank you for this! I shall give this a shot later today

Comment: margin-bottom and overflow worked like a charm. Thanks!